# how to use my connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I have made a database using MSSQL.

Now I have to create a connection to my database using Visual Studio (C#). I have successfully generated a connection string which is as follows

```
Data Source=SHIRWANIPC;Initial Catalog="TEST DATABASE";Integrated Security=True
```

After Googling I have learned that to make a connection string I have to write the following statement:

```
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" +
                                       "password=password;server=serverurl;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=database; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
```

But I do not know what to put against the id, password and database arguments. Can you please provide some additional explanation? I have Googled but I think that I am not searching correctly.

Comment: You have put username and password of user created on SQL Server instance. If you don't know them, you should contact database administrator for credentials. If it's your local DB, you set up accounts during installation. Default username / password is like your windows account. You can try to use `Integrated Security=True` for windows authentication instead of `username` and `password`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to use the connection string as is:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SHIRWANIPC;Initial Catalog=TEST DATABASE;Integrated Security=True");
```

`database` is the name of the database you are connecting to. However you have `Initial Catalog` which is roughly the same.

`user id` and `password` is another authentication option. With the connection string you have, notice the `Integrated Security=true` part, connection will be authenticated under the user who runs it, so there is not need to provide user id and password.

Just note that for this to work your DB server should accept windows authentication.

Comment: (Y) I will accept this answer as soon as My account is allowed to ,it says 2 mins before accepting :(

Answer (score 1):

Database is the name of the database you created in SQL
Username will be your login account to SQL so either SA or another name
Password is of course the password used to login to sql server database

If windows authentication you will use

```
Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: so where do i look for the username and password if its a local db ? I forgot the id and pwd ,yes i used windows authentication as far as i remember

Comment: Security -> Logins. If you are in Mixed mode then you will have a user called SA, this is considered the master login. Applications should have their own login for best practice and have that account restricted to only the database you are accessing. You can go to properties on that account and reset the password.

Comment: where do i find security? Is security a tab ? i dont think i am in mixed mode as i do not recall it from installation of MS SQL or from creating database

Comment: You will want to open up a new question for those details.

Answer (score 0):

> i do not know what to put against the id,password and database
>   arguments

**ID :** you need to give the SQL-Server UserName with which account you want to login.

**Password :** you need to provide the `password` which was assigned/created at the time of SQL Server installation.(you should know that)

**Database :** it is the name of the Database to which you want to connect in Sql Server.

**Note:**
You need to know that there are basically two different modes by which you can connect to Sql-Server.

**1.SQL-Server Authentication:** in this mode you need to provide the `User ID` and `Password`.

So the connection string would be:

```
"user id=username;password=Mypassword;server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;
        database=database;connection timeout=30";
```

**2.Windows Authentication :** in this mode you don't need to provide the `User ID` and `Password`.

So the connection string would be:

```
server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=database;connection timeout=30;
```